# how to setup a project with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have inherited a react/next.js project and below is the content of package.json file. I cloned the project and ran npm install, which looks like installs the dependencies. but when I try to run sequelize db:migrate , it doesn't work. shouldn't npm install all the required dependencies for me?

```
{
  "name": "tstar",
  "version": "3.3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.13",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.39",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "next": "9.1.7",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.7",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.7",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably a PATH issue, can u try `node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate`? :)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not diagnostic.

Comment: @HalilÇakar - that was it. I navigated to node_modules/.bin and it recognizes the sequelize command. but i need to run db:migrate command from root directory, because the config files are in the root directory, required by db:migrate command. so I tried  -> node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate, from root. and I get  following error 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. How can i run the command from the root directory?

Comment: Hey ozil, probably like i said before, it's a PATH problem, this sequelize should give you some intro to use it globally, or what you do, on your project file where ever it is, should be also the path where your node_modules are, so on that path on terminal just type: `node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate` I believe it should work like this.